# Insert a JSON object at the end of a JSON file using shell script in linux

Tags: json, jq

I've a file ~/.docker/config.json as follows.

```
{
        "auths": {
                "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {
                        "auth": "bmFnZGVlcGdrOk5hZzEzNDFkb2NrZXJA"
                }
        }
}
```

I want to append the following JSON object to it using shell script (*.sh) in  my ubuntu 18.04.
How can I achieve this ?

```
"proxies": {
        "default": {
            "httpProxy": "http://proxy.xyz.com:123",
            "httpsProxy": "http://proxy.xyz.com:123",
            "noProxy": "127.0.0.1,localhost"
        }
    }
```

So the final file ~/.docker/config.json should look like this:

```
{
            "auths": {
                    "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {
                            "auth": "bmFnZGVlcGdrOk5hZzEzNDFkb2NrZXJA"
                    }
            },
            "proxies": {
            "default": {
                "httpProxy": "http://proxy.xyz.com:123",
                "httpsProxy": "http://proxy.xyz.com:123",
                "noProxy": "127.0.0.1,localhost"
            }
        }
}
```

How to achieve this appending JSON object to the end of a JSON file using shell scripting.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow after 10 years. SO is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself. Please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `jq` to add a new key-value pair to the object in `config.json`, then write the new object back to disk.

```
jq '.proxies = {
    "default": {
        "httpProxy": "http://proxy.xyz.com:123",
        "httpsProxy": "http://proxy.xyz.com:123",
        "noProxy": "127.0.0.1,localhost"
    }
}'  ~/.docker/config.json > tmp && mv tmp ~/.docker/config.json
```

---

Everything in `jq` is a filter: they take a stream of JSON values as inputs, and return a stream of JSON values as output. Assignment is no different.

In the filter `x = y`, `x` is a path expression and `y` is an ordinary filter. `x` is evaluated using the input to determine the "target" for the assignment. `y` is applied to the input, and its output is assigned to the target specific by `x`.

In this case, the input is the entire contents of `config.json`. `.proxies` specifies a key in an object, and the `{...}` expression is a filter that ignores the input and produces a JSON object. That JSON object is that added to the input under the `proxies` key, and the modified object is returned as the output, which `jq` then writes to standard output.

The result is written to a new file so that we don't overwrite `config.json` before we can read it. Assuming `jq` succeeds, we can then replace the old `config.json` with the new file `tmp`.

`jq` itself cannot write to a file, only standard output. It can read JSON values either from standard input or from files named as arguments.

Comment: Great answer & it works :) However, Curious to understand about the sequence of the 3 steps. 1st you assigned a new proxy key:value pair. Post this,2nd step  you provided a space and did ~/.docker/config.json > tmp. And 3rd step is to move tmp to the disk.  What does tmp contain initially & how does jq edit it ?

Comment: `tmp` contains nothing; it's a brand new file. Assignments work differently in `jq` than in other languages you are familiar with, but the explanation is long. I'll add that to the answer.